# DSolve returning "Indeterminate"

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.1**

I am trying to solve the following differential equation with Mathematica:

$$
z\,(1-z)\,\psi''(z)-2 z\,\psi'(z)-\frac{3}{4}\frac{\psi(z)}{z+a^2(1+z)}=0\,.
$$

In order to do this, I input

```
DSolve[(1 - z) z Z''[z] - 2 z Derivative[1][Z][z] - 
   3/4 Z[z]/(z + a^2 (1 + z)) == 0, Z[z], z]
```

Much to my amusement, Mathematica returns

```
Z[z] -> Indeterminate
```

I would like to know why this is the case. Usually, when Mathematica cannot solve a differential equation, it returns the input, but in this case it returns the above. I am currently using Mathematica v13.0.0.

Answer (score 11):

*[I'm using V13.0.1]*

There are three parts to this answer:

1. What `DSolve` does in this case.
2. How to transform the Heun equation to the OP's ODE.
3. How to get the general solution to the OP's ODE.

### First answer: What `DSolve` does

I can explain, literally, half of it:

```
ode = (1 - z) z Z''[z] - 2 z Derivative[1][Z][z] - 
    3/4 Z[z]/(z + a^2 (1 + z)) == 0;

coeff = Coefficient[-Z''[z] /. First@Solve[ode, Z''[z]], {Z'[z], 
    Z[z]}] // Simplify
(*  {2/(-1 + z), 3/(4 (-1 + z) z (z + a^2 (1 + z)))}  *)

DSolve`DSolveSecondOrderODE; (* autoload 2nd order fns *)
basis = DSolve`DSolveSecondOrderODEDump`DSolveSpecialOrder2Linear[
  coeff, z]
(*
  {Indeterminate, 
   z HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), 
     2 - 3/(4 (1 + a^2)) + 2 (-1 - a^2/(1 + a^2)), 2, 1, 2, 2, z]}
*)

basis . {C[1], C[2]}
(*  Indeterminate  *)

ode /. Z -> 
  Function[z, 
   z HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), 
     2 - 3/(4 (1 + a^2)) + 2 (-1 - a^2/(1 + a^2)), 2, 1, 2, 2, z] 
   ] // FullSimplify
(*  True  *)
```

So what's going on? WRI improved `DSolve` in V13 (see [New in 13: Symbolic & Numeric Computation](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/new-in-13-symbolic-numeric-computation/)), and I believe that's what we're seeing.  The particular solver finds half the basis for the solution space, but the other basis function comes out `Indeterminate`. This usually happens if something like `0/0` happens, which could happen because things weren't simplified carefully. (If I have time, I'll see if I can track it down.) We can see from checking with `FullSimplify` that the second basis function satisfies the `ode`.

We can also see that the standard linear combination of the basis functions results in `Indeterminate` (`basis . {C[1], C[2]}`).

Consider reporting it as a bug. Since this is new functionality, they probably have not run into this edge case.  It looks like it could be handled better.

#### How to transform the Heun equation to the OP's ODE.

@josh's interest prompted me to share the basis for one of my comments below. It is not much help to me, but maybe it will be for others.  It shows only the relationship between the OP's equation and the [Heun equation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/31).

```
odeHeun = (-q + z α β) Z[z] +
  ((-1 + z) (-a + z) γ +
      (-1 + z) z (1 + α + β - γ - δ) + 
      z (-a + z) δ) Z'[z] +
  (-1 + z) z (-a + z) Z''[z] == 0;

(* transform Heun to OP's *)
xf = Block[{HeunG = List},
  Thread[
   HeunG[a, q, α, β, γ, δ, z] -> 
    HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), -(3/(4 (1 + a^2))), 0, 1, 0, 2, z]]
  ]
(*
{a -> -(a^2/(1 + a^2)), 
 q -> -(3/(4 (1 + a^2))), α -> 0, β -> 1, γ -> 0, δ -> 2,
 z -> z}
*)

(* Check xf transforms the Heun equation to the OP's *)
Solve[odeHeun /. xf, Z''[z]] // FullSimplify
Solve[ode, Z''[z]] // FullSimplify
% === %%
(*  True  *)

(* Extract the general basis and apply xf to get OP's case *)
First@DSolve[odeHeun, Z[z], z] /. (Thread[{C[1], C[2]} -> #] & /@ 
    IdentityMatrix[2]) /. HeunG -> Inactive[HeunG]
% /. xf
% // Activate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We have `γ = 0` in solution that evaluates to `Indeterminate`. The series expansion of the general `HeunG` function shows this and `γ` a negative integer are exceptional cases (as implied in the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/31.3)):

```
Series[HeunG[a, q, α, β, γ, δ, z], {z, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<s>Possibly, the current state of knowledge means there is no way to express the complete solution, but I'm not an expert on Heun functions.  Maybe the best place to seek an answer to the question whether there is a complete solution is on one of the other mathematics sites.</s>
See below.

#### Update 2: How to get the general solution

At the singular point $z=0$, the OP's ODE has characteristic exponents (or indicial roots) $0$ and $1$.
We have one solution above $Z_1$ that solution corresponds to a series solution expanded about the singular point $z=0$ with characteristic exponent $1$.  The difference in the characteristic exponents is an integer, so there is a Frobenius solution of the form
$$ Z_2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k + a \log z \cdot Z_1 \,.$$
Whether this may be expressed in terms of higher transcendental functions is unclear to me. (I'd guess not, but I don't know.)  However, `AsymptoticDSolveValue` may be used to get a finite expansion of the Frobenius series. It takes a long time to get more than a few terms, though.

Since the ODE is linear, we may also try to solve it by reduction of order, setting $Z_2(z)=Y(z)Z_1(z)$.  This produces a general solution in terms of an unevaluated integral (which is the sole basis for guessing that a solution in terms of higher transcendental functions is not possible).

```
(* z1sol from spelunking DSolve: *)
z1sol = Z -> 
   Function[z, 
    z HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), 
      2 - 3/(4 (1 + a^2)) + 2 (-1 - a^2/(1 + a^2)), 2, 1, 2, 2, z]];

(* DSolve will do the last step in the reduction of order
 * for us, so we need only make the substitution  *)
odeY = odeHeun /. xf /. Z -> Function[z, Y[z] Z[z]] /. z1sol // 
   FullSimplify;
ysol = First@DSolve[{odeY,
     (* irritating way to get the initial point for the
      * integral different than 1, which is a singular point:
      *)
     dummy'[z] == 0, dummy[1/2] == 0},
    {Y, dummy}, z];
gensol = Z -> Function @@ {z,
    (Y[z] + C[2] /. ysol) (Z[z] /. z1sol) // FullSimplify}

(* You can omit the dummy variable and edit the integral 
 * with the following substitution Rule:  *)
(*bettergensol = gensol //. Inactive[Integrate][f_,{x_,1,b_}] :>
    RuleCondition[Inactive[Integrate][f,{x,1/2,b}],True]*)

(* Check: *)
odeHeun /. xf /. gensol // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*On the `dummy` variable.*
Adding the dummy equation `dummy'[z] == 0` makes the system one dimension larger.  This can have consequences, sometimes ones you would wish to avoid like `DSolve` thinking the system is too complicated to try to solve (a problem in previous version, which I assume is still present).  However, starting the integral at a point where `HeunG` is undefined (or `Indeterminate` in this case) is rather unhelpful.  The replacement `Rule` method for `bettergensol` is probably the better way to handle the integral.  The `dummy` method was to show that there is a way to get `DSolve` to do it for you.  There does not seem to be any other way to tell `DSolve` where to start the integral.

### Summary/synopsis

1. This is a bug.  The fact that `gensol` is easily obtained by standard methods shows that `DSolve` could be improved in its handling of the Heun equation.  Even if that were not possible, the `Indeterminate` result for one of the basis functions should be handled better.
2. One may obtain the Frobenius series with `order = 3; AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, Z, {z, 0, order}]`, if that is desired.
3. `HeunG` is the solution to the Heun equation corresponding to the characteristic exponent `0` at the singular point `z == 0` for which `HeunG[..., 0] = 1`. It is denoted $H\!\ell$ in [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/31.3); the solution in `z1sol` corresponds to eq. [(31.3.5)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/31.3#E5). (I'm not an expert, so let me know if I made any blunders.)
4. `HeunG[-(1/2), -(11/8), 2, 1, 2, 2, 2.]` is another bug, which I will report to WRI. It is obtained by setting `a -> 1`, `z -> 2.` in the `HeunG` factor in `z1sol`. It happens for most settings of `a` as well. Note `0`, `1`, `∞` and the first argument of `HeunG` are singular points of the Heun equation. When the first argument is equal to `0` or `1` (confluent case) or `z` is equal to one of singular points, sometimes `HeunG` does not evaluate or returns `Indeterminate`.

Comment: `HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), -(3/(4 (1 + a^2))), 0, 1, 0, 2, z]` appears to be the first solution-basis function, but it evaluates to `Indeterminate`.

Comment: I don't have access to it, but would be interesting if we could compare to Maple. I will see if I can get Maple if nobody adds anything

Comment: I can only add that the `HeunG[]` expression in my previous comment is a formal solution of a Heun equation that is equivalent to the OP's ODE. I cannot explain why it evaluates to `Indeterminate`.

Comment: The situation seems like a bug. As you suggested it should be reported

Comment: @Michael E2:  Do I need to load a a package for `basis = DSolve`DSolveSecondOrderODEDump`DSolveSpecialOrder2Linear[
  coeff, z]`  as Mathematica returns unevaluated on my machine for V. 13.

Comment: @josh It's autoloaded, like a lot of internal stuff, which I failed to check. One could evaluate the OP's `DSolve[..]` code, or just evaluate ``DSolve`DSolveSecondOrderODE``. Answer code updated -- thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5):

> I don't have access to it, but would be interesting if we could
> compare to Maple. I will see if I can get Maple if nobody adds
> anything

Maple 2022 can't solve it. It gives solution in terms of  [DESol](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DESol)

> DESol is a data structure to represent the solution of a differential
> equation. It is to dsolve as RootOf is to solve.

Here is its attempt

```
    ode:=z*(1-z)*diff(y(z),z$2)-2*z*diff(y(z),z)-3/4*y(z)/(z+a^2*(1+z))=0
    infolevel[dsolve]:=5;
    dsolve(ode)
```

It gives

```
Methods for second order ODEs:
--- Trying classification methods ---
trying a quadrature
checking if the LODE has constant coefficients
checking if the LODE is of Euler type
trying a symmetry of the form [xi=0, eta=F(x)]
   testing BRANCH 1 ->
   testing BRANCH 2 ->
   testing BRANCH 3 ->
   testing BRANCH 4 ->
   testing BRANCH 5 ->
   testing BRANCH 6 ->
checking if the LODE is missing 'y' 
-> Trying a Liouvillian solution using Kovacic's algorithm
<- No Liouvillian solutions exists
-> Trying a solution in terms of special functions:
   -> Bessel
   -> elliptic
   -> Legendre
   -> Whittaker
      -> hyper3: Equivalence to 1F1 under 'a power @ Moebius'
   -> hypergeometric
      -> heuristic approach
      -> hyper3: Equivalence to 2F1, 1F1 or 0F1 under 'a power @ Moebius'
         -> trying extended approach, based on solving the ODE satisfied by the "derivative" of y(z)
            -> ODE succesfully computed; trying to solve: diff(diff(y(z),z),z) = -(5*a^2*z^2+2*a^2*z-a^2+5*z^2-2*z)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)*diff(y(z),z)-1/4*y(z)*(16*a^2*z^2-8*a^2*z-8*a^2+16*z^2-13*z-3)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)^2
         <- extended approach, failed in solving the ODE for the "derivative" of y(z)
   -> Mathieu
      -> Equivalence to the rational form of Mathieu ODE under 'a power @ Moebius'
         -> trying extended approach, based on solving the ODE satisfied by the "derivative" of y(z)
            -> ODE succesfully computed; trying to solve: diff(diff(y(z),z),z) = -(5*a^2*z^2+2*a^2*z-a^2+5*z^2-2*z)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)*diff(y(z),z)-1/4*y(z)*(16*a^2*z^2-8*a^2*z-8*a^2+16*z^2-13*z-3)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)^2
         <- extended approach, failed in solving the ODE for the "derivative" of y(z)
trying a solution in terms of MeijerG functions
-> Heun: Equivalence to the GHE or one of its 4 confluent cases under 'a power @ Moebius'
-> trying a solution of the form r0(x) * Y + r1(x) * Y' where Y = exp(int(r(x), dx)) * 2F1([a1, a2], [b1], f)
-> Tackling the "Normal Form" of the given linear ODE:
   trying a symmetry of the form [xi=0, eta=F(x)]
      testing BRANCH 1 ->
      testing BRANCH 2 ->
      testing BRANCH 3 ->
      testing BRANCH 5 ->
      testing BRANCH 6 ->
-> Tackling the linear ODE using alternative approaches:
   trying differential order: 2; exact nonlinear
   trying symmetries linear in x and y(x)
   trying to convert to a linear ODE with constant coefficients
      testing BRANCH 1 ->
   trying 2nd order, integrating factor of the form mu(x,y)
   Trying an integrating factor as the solution to the adjoint linear ODE
   -> Trying a solution in terms of special functions:
      -> Bessel
      -> elliptic
      -> Legendre
      -> Whittaker
         -> hyper3: Equivalence to 1F1 under 'a power @ Moebius'
      -> hypergeometric
         -> heuristic approach
         -> hyper3: Equivalence to 2F1, 1F1 or 0F1 under 'a power @ Moebius'
            -> trying extended approach, based on solving the ODE satisfied by the "derivative" of y(z)
               -> ODE succesfully computed; trying to solve: diff(diff(y(z),z),z) = -(3*a^2*z^3-9*a^2*z^2+3*a^2*z+3*z^3+3*a^2-9*z^2+6*z)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)/(8*a^2*z^2+8*a^2*z+8*z^2+3*z-3)*diff(y(z),z)-1/4*y(z)*(72*a^2*z^2-48*a^2*z-24*a^2+57*z^2-66*z+9)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)^2/(8*a^2*z^2+8*a^2*z+8*z^2+3*z-3)
            <- extended approach, failed in solving the ODE for the "derivative" of y(z)
      -> Mathieu
         -> Equivalence to the rational form of Mathieu ODE under 'a power @ Moebius'
            -> trying extended approach, based on solving the ODE satisfied by the "derivative" of y(z)
               -> ODE succesfully computed; trying to solve: diff(diff(y(z),z),z) = -(3*a^2*z^3-9*a^2*z^2+3*a^2*z+3*z^3+3*a^2-9*z^2+6*z)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)/(8*a^2*z^2+8*a^2*z+8*z^2+3*z-3)*diff(y(z),z)-1/4*y(z)*(72*a^2*z^2-48*a^2*z-24*a^2+57*z^2-66*z+9)/(a^2*z+a^2+z)/z/(-1+z)^2/(8*a^2*z^2+8*a^2*z+8*z^2+3*z-3)
            <- extended approach, failed in solving the ODE for the "derivative" of y(z)
   -> Tackling the linear ODE using alternative approaches:
      trying 2nd order exact linear
      trying symmetries linear in x and y(x)
      trying to convert to a linear ODE with constant coefficients
         testing BRANCH 1 ->
      trying to convert to an ODE of Bessel type
   trying to convert to an ODE of Bessel type
   -> trying reduction of order to Riccati
      Chini's absolute invariant is: (1/3)*(a^2*z^2+4*a^2*z+a^2+z^2+2*z)^2/(z*(a^2*z+a^2+z)*(-1+z))
      trying Riccati sub-methods:
         -> trying a symmetry pattern of the form [F(x)*G(y), 0]
         -> trying a symmetry pattern of the form [0, F(x)*G(y)]
         -> trying a symmetry pattern of the form [F(x),G(x)*y+H(x)]
--- Trying Lie symmetry methods, 2nd order ---
 -> Computing symmetries using: way = 3
                             [0, y]

 <- successful computation of symmetries.
 -> Computing symmetries using: way = 5
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to check this!

Comment: Do you know if it's similar to `DifferentialRoot[Function[{Z, z}, {(1 - z) z Z''[z] - 2 z Derivative[1][Z][z] - 3/4 Z[z]/(z + a^2 (1 + z)) == 0, Z[0] == Z0, Z'[0] == Z1}]]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think `DifferentialRoot` in Mathematica is like  [ODESolStruc](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve/ODESolStruc)  in Maple but I never was able to confirm this. Maple says _For high order ODEs it may happen that dsolve succeeds in reducing the order of the ODE but not in solving the problem to the end. In those cases, the answer is expressed using ODESolStruc._  The rule of thumb I use is that if Maple returns `ODESolStruc` or `DESol` then the ODE is _not solved_. And if Mathematica returns `DifferentialRoot` then also the ode is _not solved_.

Comment: For DESol, I read in Maple's docs, "DESol...is to dsolve as RootOf is to solve." I think of `DifferentialRoot` is to `DSolve` as `Root` is to `Solve`, although each has its limitations. `DifferentialRoot` can compute numerical values of a solution and series expansions (when the ODE has polynomial coefficients and parameters are sufficiently defined). It has trouble near singular points, so my defining it in my comment at `z == 0` (e.g. IC `Z[0] == Z0`) is a mistake, I think.

Answer (score 3):

An extended comment:

My understanding is this DE can be transformed into the standard Heung DE by a suitable change of variables.  DSolve can solve the standard form:

```
sol = DSolve[ 
  y''[z] + (\[Gamma]/z + \[Delta]/(z - 1) + (
       1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta] - \[Gamma] - \[Delta])/(z - a)) y'[
      z] + (\[Alpha] \[Beta] z - q)/(z (z - 1) (z - a)) y[z] == 0, 
  y[z], z]
```

producing two solutions:

```
(* {{y[z] -> 
   C[1] HeunG[a, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], z] + 
    z^(1 - \[Gamma]) C[
     2] HeunG[a, 
      q - (-1 + \[Gamma]) (1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta] - \[Gamma] + (-1 + 
             a) \[Delta]), 1 + \[Beta] - \[Gamma], 
      1 + \[Alpha] - \[Gamma], 2 - \[Gamma], \[Delta], z]}} *)
```

I think if we either first transformed the OP's DE into standard form then execute DSolve, or even better, use the two solutions returned by DSolve for the standard form solution and then adjust the constants appropriately to match the OPs original DE.  However, I'm not initially able to make this transformation.  This might be a work-around to obtaining the solutions.

**Edit:**

Using Michael's transformation code above exactly as written, running on a clean kernel, I do not obtain an Indeterminate for the final `hDev` answer but rather 2 HeunG functions:

```
odeHeun = (-q + z \[Alpha] \[Beta]) Z[
      z] + ((-1 + z) (-a + z) \[Gamma] + (-1 + 
          z) z (1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta] - \[Gamma] - \[Delta]) + 
       z (-a + z) \[Delta]) Z'[z] + (-1 + z) z (-a + z) Z''[z] == 0;
ode = (1 - z) z Z''[z] - 2 z Derivative[1][Z][z] - 
    3/4 Z[z]/(z + a^2 (1 + z)) == 0;

(*transform Heun to OP's*)
xf = Block[{HeunG = List}, 
  Thread[HeunG[a, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], z] -> 
    HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), -(3/(4 (1 + a^2))), 0, 1, 0, 2, z]]]
(*{a->-(a^2/(1+a^2)),q->-(3/(4 (1+a^2))),\[Alpha]->0,\[Beta]->1,\
\[Gamma]->0,\[Delta]->2,z->z}*)

(*Check xf transforms the Heun equation to the OP's*)
sVal1 = Solve[odeHeun /. xf, Z''[z]] // FullSimplify
sVal2 = Solve[ode, Z''[z]] // FullSimplify
sVal1 === sVal2
(*True*)

(*Extract the general basis and apply xf to get OP's case*)
hDev = First@
    DSolve[odeHeun, Z[z], z] /. (Thread[{C[1], C[2]} -> #] & /@ 
     IdentityMatrix[2]) /. HeunG -> Inactive[HeunG]
hDev /. xf
hDev // Activate

(* {{Z[z] -> 
       HeunG[a, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], z]}, {Z[z] -> 
       z^(1 - \[Gamma])
         HeunG[a, 
         q - (-1 + \[Gamma]) (1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta] - \[Gamma] + (-1 + 
                a) \[Delta]), 1 + \[Beta] - \[Gamma], 
         1 + \[Alpha] - \[Gamma], 2 - \[Gamma], \[Delta], z]}} *)
```

Comment: I can do this transformation based on my spelunking; there is, I think, an algorithm, but I'm not famliar with it. You end up with the `Indeterminate` Heun function, so I don't see that it really helped. I left [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266468/dsolve-returning-indeterminate/266484?noredirect=1#comment664343_266484) in the hopes that something else to try might suggest itself.  `Series[HeunG[a, q, α, β, γ, δ, z], {z, 0, 2}]` suggests why `γ=0` may be a problem.

Comment: I added the transformation to my answer. Take a look if you're interested.

Comment: @Michael E2:  I ran your transformation code on my machine under ver 13 exactly as written and obtain two Heung functions for the final answer and no Indeterminate although it's a bit tough to follow your code and maybe I'm not understanding something.

Comment: You need to plug in the parameter values in the expression at the end of your post.  Apply `... /. Block[{HeunG = List},
 Thread[HeunG[a, q, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], z] -> 
   HeunG[-(a^2/(1 + a^2)), -(3/(4 (1 + a^2))), 0, 1, 0, 2, z]]
 ]` -- Then you get `Indeterminate`. I gotta go somewhere, so I'll double-check later.

Comment: I though the `hDev/.xf` construct did this.  I'll work on it.  Thank!  You guys do brilliant work here with DEs I think.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I was in a rush before and didn't look at the code carefully.  Yeah, `hDev /. xf` should do it, but your last line lacks the `./ xf` and just has `hDev // Activate`.  You maybe meant `hDev = hDev /. xf` in the second-to-line, or `% // Activate` in the last, or something similar.

Comment: Ok.  I see that now.   My mistake.   Should be` hDev=hDev/.xf //Activate`

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in 13.1. The following is screen shot

[image]