# How to set integral starting from 0 in the symbolic solution to ODE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following ODE

```
Bfull'[t] == - (p0/(
    p0 + (1 - p0) E^Integrate[α[s], {s, 0, t}])) * α[
    t] (S[t] - Bfull[t]) + α[t]*c + δ * Bfull[t]
```

where α and S are some functions. I would like the solution to integrate from 0, instead of 1, which is the default of mathematica.

Comment: Did you try to specify `α[s]` and `α[t]` and `S[t]`?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like the solution to integrate from 0, instead of 1

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = Bfull'[
   t] == -(p0/(p0 + (1 - p0) E^
           Integrate[\[Alpha][s], {s, 0, t}]))*\[Alpha][
     t] (S[t] - Bfull[t]) + \[Alpha][t]*c + \[Delta]*Bfull[t]
sol = Bfull[t] /. First@DSolve[ode, Bfull[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
sol /. Inactive[Integrate][any_, {any2_, 1, t}] :> 
  Inactive[Integrate][any, {any2, 0, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want also the integrals that have `K[1]` and `K[2]` to start from 0, then do the same for these.

```
sol /. Inactive[Integrate][any_, {any2_, 1, K[1]}] :> 
  Inactive[Integrate][any, {any2, 0, K[1]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a dummy variable in
[DSolve returning "Indeterminate"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266468/dsolve-returning-indeterminate/266484#266484)
to set location of the initial condition, which in turn sets the starting point for an unevaluated integral.

But in this case we could just set an initial condition for `Bfull` with an arbitrary parameter, and `DSolve` can still handle the system:

```
DSolve[
 {Bfull'[t] == -(p0/(p0 +
    (1 - p0) E^Integrate[α[s], {s, 0, t}]))*
    α[t] (S[t] - Bfull[t]) + α[t]*c + δ*Bfull[t], 
  Bfull[0] == B0},
 Bfull, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]